# How to change thumbnail position

Tags: css, wordpress, position, thumbnails

The thumbnail at my blog theme ("nova theme") is positioned at the top of the post (on the static page that shows the last posts.

How can i change it to be aligned at the left of the text with excerpt?

This is how it is now: http://vocemaisvalor.com/blog/
This is how it should look like: http://viverdeblog.com/

Thank you!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always include the code relevant for your question within the question body. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Appreciated your observation. The point is that i don't know what is the code i need to change to change the thumbnail position.

Comment: :) you are asking how to change the programming of a software piece called a Wordpress theme. Find a theme that has thumbnails the way you like them.

Comment: Thank you Andrei Draganescu. I know its possible to find another theme that has the same thumbnails i need. However a theme is not only about thumbnails.

I trust that there are people who knows its easy to change that code.

I've already changes a few codes on the theme. Pretty nice thing to do. Now trying to find the place where i can change the thumbnail. Changing the theme is giving-up, and if i change, will be harder to find a theme that fits.

Comment: I know that there are ninjas that know how to solve it. My hope is to one of them comming to help!